# xsd format number , 5 decimal places

Tags: oracle, xsd-validation

I have xsd code which is printing LINE_AMOUNT value as 14,952.59 , now i want to display this as 14,952.59000(5 decimal places).

How to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/316)

**Query 1** Either (if you want to use the current NLS values for decimal and thousands characters):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         14952.59,
         'FM9G999G999G999G990D00000'
       )
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/316/0)**:

```
| TO_CHAR(14952.59,'FM9G999G999G999G990D00000') |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|                                  14,952.59000 |
```

**Query 2** or:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         14952.59,
         'FM9,999,999,999,990.00000'
       )
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/316/1)**:

```
| TO_CHAR(14952.59,'FM9,999,999,999,990.00000') |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|                                  14,952.59000 |
```

---

**Update**: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/316/1)

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_NUMBER( 
           '13,214,952.59',
           'FM9G999G999G999G990D99999'
         ),
         'FM9G999G999G999G990D00000'
       ) AS formatted_value
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/322/0)**:

```
|  FORMATTED_VALUE |
|------------------|
| 13,214,952.59000 |
```

**Query 4**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_NUMBER( 
           '13,214,952.59',
           'FM9,999,999,999,990.99999'
         ),
         'FM9,999,999,999,990.00000'
       ) AS formatted_value
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/322/1)**:

```
|  FORMATTED_VALUE |
|------------------|
| 13,214,952.59000 |
```

Comment: Thank you so much MTO,  i need to implement this in xml report (oracle apps report), do you have any idea?

Comment: @Rajesh123 Update your question with your current code, an example of your data and re-tag the question to include `oraclereports` and you may find someone who can answer that. Currently your question is tagged `Oracle` (which is just the database and not a catch-all for all Oracle products) so I've given you an Oracle SQL answer as that appeared to be what you wanted.

Comment: @MTO i have output data is like 14,952.59 , but not 14952.59, i need to implement using 14,952.59 value

Comment: @Rajesh123 Updated

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work for you I think.

```
select trim(to_char(14952.59,9999999999.99999)) from dual


OUTPUT
14952.59000
```

Comment: Thank you Vivek, but i have 14,952.59 , so i need 14,592.59000 as well it using in xml report (rtf template)

Comment: Do you need "," separator for numbers then you can try this "select trim(to_char(14952.59,'9,99,99,99,999.99999')) from dual", but I don't have idea about "rtf" template.